# Program needs 2 roman numbers as input and one as output. This solution here seems to hang. What can i do to prevent hanging?

Tags: c++

The solution I am writing here is an exercise from my homework. Program needs 2 roman numbers as input, adds them and prints output in roman. When I submit this as homework it doesn't work because this solution here seems to be hanging and it passes the time limit allowed by teacher. What can I do to prevent hanging?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int dec, decdig1, decdig2, decdig3, decdig4, rem;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    char s, t, d, c;
    cin.get(t);

    while(t!='\n')
    {
        s=t;
        cin.get(t);
        if(s=='I'&&t!='V'&&t!='X')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 1;
        }
        if((s=='I'&&t=='V')||(s=='I'&&t=='X'))
        {
            sum2 = sum2 - 1;
        }
        if(s=='V')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 5;
        }
        if(s=='X'&&t!='L'&&t!='C')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 10;
        }
        if((s=='X'&&t=='L')||(s=='X'&&t=='C'))
        {
            sum2 = sum2 - 10;
        }
        if(s=='L')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 50;
        }
        if(s=='C'&&t!='D'&&t!='M')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 100;
        }
        if((s=='C'&&t=='D')||(s=='C'&&t=='M'))
        {
            sum2 = sum2 - 100;
        }
        if(s=='D')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 500;
        }
        if(s=='M')
        {
            sum2 = sum2 + 1000;
        }   
    }


    cin.get(c);

    while(c!='\n')
    {
        d=c;
        cin.get(c);
        if(d=='I'&&c!='V'&&c!='X')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 1;
        }
        if((d=='I'&&c=='V')||(d=='I'&&c=='X'))
        {
            sum1 = sum1 - 1;
        }
        if(d=='V')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 5;
        }
        if(d=='X'&&c!='L'&&c!='C')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 10;
        }
        if((d=='X'&&c=='L')||(d=='X'&&c=='C'))
        {
            sum1 = sum1 - 10;
        }
        if(d=='L')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 50;
        }
        if(d=='C'&&c!='D'&&c!='M')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 100;
        }
        if((d=='C'&&c=='D')||(d=='C'&&c=='M'))
        {
            sum1 = sum1 - 100;
        }
        if(d=='D')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 500;
        }
        if(d=='M')
        {
            sum1 = sum1 + 1000;
        }   
    }

    dec = sum1 + sum2;


    decdig1 = dec/1000;
    rem = dec%1000;
    decdig2= rem/100;
    rem= rem%100;
    decdig3= rem/10;
    rem= rem%10;
    decdig4= rem/1;
    rem= rem%1;

    if(decdig1 == 1)
    {
        cout<<"M";
    }

    if(decdig2== 1)
    {
        cout<<"C";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 2)
    {
        cout<<"CC";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 3)
    {
        cout<<"CCC";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 4)
    {
        cout<<"CD";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 5)
    {
        cout<<"D";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 6)
    {
        cout<<"DC";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 7)
    {
        cout<<"DCC";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 8)
    {
        cout<<"DCCC";
    }
    else if(decdig2 == 9)
    {
        cout<<"CM";
    }


    if(decdig3 == 1)
    {
        cout<<"X";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 2)
    {
        cout<<"XX";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 3)
    {
        cout<<"XXX";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 4)
    {
        cout<<"XL";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 5)
    {
        cout<<"L";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 6)
    {
        cout<<"LX";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 7)
    {
        cout<<"LXX";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 8)
    {
        cout<<"LXXX";
    }
    else if(decdig3 == 9)
    {
        cout<<"XC";
    }

    if(decdig4 == 1)
    {
        cout<<"I";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 2)
    {
        cout<<"II";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 3)
    {
        cout<<"III";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 4)
    {
        cout<<"IV";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 5)
    {
        cout<<"V";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 6)
    {
        cout<<"VI";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 7)
    {
        cout<<"VII";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 8)
    {
        cout<<"VIII";
    }
    else if(decdig4 == 9)
    {
        cout<<"IX";
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know what input causes the program to not respond?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that I cannot use arrays or strings, just the basic stuff. At most I can use functions.

Comment: It works for all the inputs. It just seems to pass the time limit and I still haven't figured out why.

Comment: How are you timing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Of course without the test cases I can't really tell where the problem is, but its likely to be because of the while loop checking for the '\n'.
The last line in the input might not have a new empty line which may cause it to be stuck in an infinite loop for the last character causing the time limit.
I recommend using something as:

```
while(cin.get(c)) { }
```

instead of your second while loop.

Comment: This method doesn't output the solution

Comment: It'll remain in an infinite loop of course if you're trying to run the program on console without an input file which is a case unlike the predefined test cases in your assignment.
Try to use a file with the wanted test case or if your IDE support defining program input before running.